# Copy from remote server which doesn't have rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, remote, file-copy

I need to recursively copy a folder from a Ubuntu remote server where I have `ssh` access. I don't want to follow symbolic links, nor to copy permissions/owner/group, because my client system (Ubuntu too) doesn't have the same users as the server.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102211/rsync-ignore-owner-group-time-and-perms) `rsync` solution could be the best one.
But the server does not have `rsync` and I can't install it there; so that command gives me error.

Is there another way to copy the remote folder?

Comment: tar or cpio ... these do have limitations but they copy symlinks as symlinks

Comment: or upload your own copy of the `rsync` executable ... it does not need root permissions to work your own files

Comment: i had same situation at crazydomains - i just downloaded source of rsync from here https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/ - then compiled, placed in remote user's `~/bin` dir,  and used `--rsync-path=/home/user/bin/rsync` on local rsync command. worked a treat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the permission to use [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) on your local machine, install the [`sshfs` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sshfs). SSHFS lets you access remote files via normal filesystem access: it mounts a directory tree accessed over SFTP. You only need to have SFTP access on the remote side (which is enabled by default with OpenSSH on Ubuntu). Once the remote directory is mounted, you can use the tools of your choice to manipulate files, without having to care whether they're local or remote.

```
mkdir ~/net/remote-server
sshfs remote-server:/ ~/net/remote-server
rsync -a --no-copy-links ~/net/remote-server/remote/path/ /local/path/
fusermount -u ~/net/remote-server
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `scp -r` to copy files recursively between different hosts. Your syntax could be like `scp -r user@Ubuntu-Server:/home/myuser ./from_Ubuntu_server`

Besides, you might be able to upload your local `rsync` binary using scp to the Ubuntu server and add the `--rsync-path=/home/myuser/rsync` to your original `rsync` command to let your client `rsync` know which `rsync` it should invoke on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: your tip on using `--rsync-path=/...` helped me on my remote host where i was able to easily compile my own copy of `rsync` from source, and point to it from local rsync cmd. worked a treat! thx sooooooo much....

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tar` and `ssh`.

As an example, **to upload** the contents of a local directory `somewhere_local`, via ssh, to the path `/somewhere`

```bash
tar czf - -C ./somewhere_local . | ssh {yourserver} 'tar xzf - -C /somewhere'
```

Alternatively, **to download** the contents of a remote directory `/somewhere`, via ssh, to the path `./somewhere_local`

```bash
ssh {yourserver} "tar czf - -C /somewhere ." | tar xzf - -C somewhere_local
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question which suggests the OP needs to use sudo.

Comment: That copies local to remote; it should be reversed `ssh @remote "tar cf- from" | tar xf-` for this question.
Both `tar z` and `ssh -C` is almost certainly a waste of CPU; even one is needed only if large data or slow net.
Using `v` on both concurrent tars will often produce very confusing output; I would do it only on the destination.